# ignoring file /[path]/libGooglePlus.a, missing required architecture i386 in file[path]/libGooglePlus.a

Tags: iphone, ios, shared-libraries, google-plus

in my google plus code i get this error. what problem for this error in my code

```
    _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGooglePlusUniversal.a(GPPShareBuilderImpl.o)
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGooglePlusUniversal.a(GPPSignIn.o)
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGooglePlusUniversal.a(GPPSignIn.o)
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGooglePlusUniversal.a(GPPSignIn.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: have you set header search paths and other linker flags my friend?? and also you have to add lots of frameworks...

Comment: explain me in details dear friend please

Answer (score 0):

have you added frameworks like... libxml2.dylib, security,mapkit,corelocation,systemconfiguration frameworks etc....?? if not then add those frameworks and then check...

Let me know it is working or not!!!!!

Happy coding!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This warning means that you're trying to use library made for Device (ARM) with your Simulator (i386).